# Runtime error 1004 on autofilling data

Tags: excel, vba

My code is supposed to autofill my "IF" formula of K2=J2 and so on in Column "L" but is encountering runtime error 1004.

I want the macro to complete the entirety of the column till it hits the last row with data in Column K.

Code:

```
Sub SiteAccess()

Dim mySheet As Worksheet, myOtherSheet As Worksheet, myBook As Workbook
Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
Set mySheet = myBook.Sheets("SiteAccessReports")
Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet1")

Dim ff As Long

ff = myOtherSheet.Range("L2:L" & myOtherSheet.Cells(myOtherSheet.Rows.Count, "L").End(xlUp).Row).Count
With Sheets("Sheet1")
.Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""No"",""Yes"")"
Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & ff), Type:=xlFillDefault 'Error Line
End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there is a better answer but for want of any other so far:

```vb
Sub SiteAccess()
    Dim myBook As Workbook
    Dim myOtherSheet As Worksheet
    Dim ff As Long
    Set myBook = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set myOtherSheet = myBook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ff = myOtherSheet.Range("K1:K" & myOtherSheet.Cells(myOtherSheet.Rows.Count, "K") _
    .End(xlUp).Row).Count
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        .Range("L2").Select
        .Range("L2").Formula = "=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""No"",""Yes"")"
        Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range("L2:L" & ff), Type:=xlFillDefault
    End With
End Sub
```